# Rendering obj files with three.js, nothing shows up?

Tags: 3d, rendering, three.js

I am trying to render a .obj using three.js and i have looked at a couple of examples and figured how to do it but my html code doesn't seem to work! All i see is a black screen. I have attached the code below, what am i doing wrong?. I am a total noob at this so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<body>
    <div id="info">
    <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - OBJLoader test
    </div>

    <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


        init();
        animate();


        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.z = 100;

            // scene

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
            scene.add( ambient );

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
            directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
            scene.add( directionalLight );


            // model

            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            loader.load( "/obj/smiley.obj", function ( object ) {
            scene.add( object );
            } );

            //

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

        }

        function render() {

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you post smiley.obj somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an EventListener:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

    scene.add( event.content );

});
loader.load( "/obj/smiley.obj' );
```

Comment: I made that change but still nothing. Just a blank screen1

Comment: So now can you post the object? Maybe there is a problem with it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hu3ca3pfut7szoj/smiley.obj This is the object! It seems to working on p3d.in. http://p3d.in/rfATm

Comment: Yes the problem was with your obj file. Open the file in a text editor and search for backslashes (\\). These need to be removed (ie. current line must be joined with the next one so 3 numbers appear on the line). Three.js cannot parse this type on lines inside an obj file. Also it would be a good idea to triangulate the model when you export from your package as the model has some quads in it instead of plain triangles.

Comment: I created a new object with all triangles and no backslashes(\), a fairly simple one. Still nothing!  https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2rgpsg5hteuz2n/test2.obj

Comment: If I take the example webgl_loader_obj.html and replace the loaded model with yours on line 108 (release 58) I see it perfectly.

Comment: Something is wrong with my chrome. I see the object perfectly in Firefox. I would probably try and fix that. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Download the latest Chrome.

Comment: If some comment was useful, I would appreciate an up vote. Up arrow on the left of the comment. You have to move your mouse there to see the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Does your .obj file comes with an attached .mtl file?
They must be placed in the same folder or the OBJLoader will not load anything.